# SSH - remote fowarding - ensure connection is always active

Tags: ssh

I have 2 servers.

- `Server A` is behind a router, to which I have no admin access.

  - It has a user: `userA`
- `Server B (example.com)` is a cloud server with a public ip.

  - It has a user: `userB`

I am running the following command on `Server A`, to forward any connections made to `Server B` on Port `8022` back to `Server A` on port `22`:
`ssh -R *:8022:localhost:22 userB@example.com`

This creates a ssh connection and I have a session open for `userB@example.com`

If I then open another terminal (on another computer) and ssh into `userB@example.com` and once connected run `ssh userA@localhost -p 8022` I have an active ssh connection to `Server A`

This is new to me but all seems to make sense.

I would like to ensure that the inital remote forwarding connection `ssh -R` is always active. This means if the connection drops I need it to reconnect. If `Server A` reboots I need it to connect on startup.

How would I go about doing this?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski That seemed to do half the trick. I posted an answer below. If you see any room for improvement feel free to answer / comment!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Kamil's comment I used `autossh`.

If I reboot `Server B` however `autossh` seemed to exit.

I wrote the following script and have it running every minute on a cron on `Server A`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /proc/$(cat /home/userA/tunnel.pid)/status ]; then
    nohup autossh -M 20000 -R 8022:localhost:22 userB@example.com -N > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo $! > /home/userA/tunnel.pid
fi
```

This seems to ensure that the ssh connection is always running (within a minute), regardless of either server closing the connection or rebooting.

If there is a better approach, or I am misunderstanding the full potential of `autossh` I will accept a better answer